# Can't capture a redirected link using requests module

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, python-requests

When I use a [link](https://shapeyourcity.ca/32362/widgets/132002/documents/87994) in a browser, it gets redirected, but when I use it in a script, it stays the same. I'm trying to find any way to grab the redirected link using the original one. My main goal here is to download a pdf file. The pdf file shows up when the url gets redirected.

To be specific, I want to use this link `https://shapeyourcity.ca/32362/widgets/132002/documents/87994` within the script below to capture the redirected link so that I can later use the redirected link to download the pdf file.

I've tried with:

```
import requests

link = 'https://shapeyourcity.ca/32362/widgets/132002/documents/87994'

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/103.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
}
with requests.Session() as s:
    s.headers.update(headers)
    res = s.get(link,allow_redirects=True)
    print(res.url)
```

When I run the script, I end up getting the same link. However, it gets redirected in the browser.

Question: How can I grab a redirected link using requests module?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `/download` to the URL:

```py
import requests

url = "https://shapeyourcity.ca/32362/widgets/132002/documents/87994"

with open("file.pdf", "wb") as f_out:
    resp = requests.get(url + "/download")
    print("Downloading from", resp.url)
    f_out.write(resp.content)
```

Prints:

```
Downloading from https://ehq-production-canada.s3.ca-central-1.amazonaws.com/e1c3b8b12b4a1e1604726ae8994703200c063dad/original/1661977908/12da2a93dcb772a56178c9b34d4bc429_Notification_postcard.pdf?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAIBJCUKKD4ZO4WUUA%2F20220903%2Fca-central-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20220903T130651Z&X-Amz-Expires=300&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Signature=f81b11379be56a2201bc70ac8c4dbb8f541d4a1247a233f81be74f4d27b1b2e5
```

and saves `file.pdf` (screenshot from Firefox):

[image]